# Marking point with the single extreme value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, mapping, timestamp

I am working on a system with a continuously updating database of earthquakes. For one of the presentation, I want a map showing the last events. I have the timestamp for each event, so I have made a virtual field, `"age"`, calculating

```
hour(now() - timestamp)
```

so I have the age of each event and can use that for a graduated symbology.

[image: Current symbology]

But, I would also like to have a special symbol for the single newest event. As I have the data in a PostGIS database, I could make an additional layer based on the query:

```sql
 select *
 from event
 order by timestamp desc
 limit 1
```

but if possible, I would like to have that event within the symbology of the layer that I already have. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Can you provide your current symbology settings?

Comment: @Erik, added symbology

Comment: Convert your Graduated symbology to a Rule-Based ;)

Comment: @MrXsquared, can you make an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Rule based symbology](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#hard-fa-rule-based-classification) like this, in your case you should use `minimum`:

[image]

Comment: Just one addition, As I always want to be able to see the latest event, I had to use "Symbol levels" to get it on top

Comment: Ok nice! If you want to use "graduated" symbols, maybe it will also be easier to duplicate the layer and use the duplicate to only display the min/max value.